# HTML Background Positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to determine how to do a background like having a negative margin. Here is a picture of what I have done as of now

[image: http://imgur.com/rYqDn5l]

The picture below show what I want as a result

[image: http://imgur.com/E5MMUSt]

Im trying to use a negative margin but no luck at all. Here is my code as of now

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
                  <div class="navbar navbar-custom radius-fixer nomargin" role="navigation">
                              <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="navbar-collapse collapse nopaddingright">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">      
                                  <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">HOME</a></li>        
                                  <li><a href="about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="faq">FAQ</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="contact-us">CONTACT US</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="online-forms">ONLINE FORMS</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="virtual-clinic-tour">VIRTUAL CLINIC TOUR</a></li>    
                                  <li><a href="blog" class="noborder">BLOG</a></li>              
                                </ul>                       
                              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                          </div><!--/.container-fluid --> 
</div>

<div class="clearfix" id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flexslider nomargin">
                      <ul class="slides">
                        <li>
                            <img src="SLIDER1"  />
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <img src="SLIDER2"  />
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <img src="SLIDER3"  />
                          </li>
                      </ul>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

FOR MY CSS

```
  #main{
  background: #bf35bc;
  background-position: top;

}
```

A reply is really appreciated.

Comment: you can try putting a margin-bottom (-) or margin-top (+) to the nav bar so it would overlap the background. Edit: can you put the code in jsfiddle so we can see it as well.

Comment: @nCore putting negative margin won't work here is the result http://imgur.com/RXhZLWw the navbar will disappear

Comment: @web-tiki i am using bootstrap.

Comment: put a z-index: to the nav bar so it would put it in front of the main.

Comment: @nCore wont work still mate.

Comment: post your code instead so people can try it.

Comment: here is the code http://www.bootply.com/tpZhKVW4cn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want by applying a negative top margin to the `main` element:

```
margin-top: -40px;
```

That will pull the div up. See http://jsfiddle.net/raad/f6r1Lvf9/embedded/result/

**EDIT**

I have forked the Bootply example from the question, and added a negative top margin: http://www.bootply.com/5n8DsKXPQG
It appears to do what is needed.

Comment: I tried it but I don't get the result same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

this is negative top margin: `margin-top: -50px;`

so try

```
#main{
   background: #bf35bc;
   background-position: top;
   margin-top: -50px;
}
```